# Passing a template-driven parameter properly into controller function

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller with a function in it that when called populates data into an ng-repeat loop.  Part of this data is a button that is supposed to call another function and pass a parameter with it that again is populated by the ng-repeat loop.

```
<button ng-click="doAction({{param}})">
```

I can see in the HTML of the Chrome inspector that the loop is placing the proper parameter in that function call, but when one of those buttons are clicked and it runs the function, it's not passing the parameter into the function, only a literal "{{param}}".

What do I do to make it pass the actual parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `param` without `{{}}`

```
<button ng-click="doAction(param)">
```

Comment: Because that parameter is being dynamically populated by an ng-repeat loop from a controller function.

Comment: How are you displaying the content? Is it combo box or drop down.... And are you displaying a button against each item?

Comment: Looks like it did pass the parameter after all using your method.  Thanks @user7.  I can't say I understand the logic behind it though.